# При некоторых случаях программа выдает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Условие задачи https://stepik.org/lesson/3363/step/4?is_exp_folded=false&unit=1135

Вся проблема моего кода в постоянной ошибке, которая вылезает всегда в разных местах:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Дима/Python/venv/Include/Kyrsick.py", line 9, in 
    math += [int(student[1])]
IndexError: list index out of range

Помогите, пожалуйста, мне с моим кодом

З.Ы. ну не пишите свой код, мне нужно понять именно свою ошибку

```
f = open('dataset_3363_4 (3).txt') #открываю файлик
math = []
fis = []
rus = []
res = [] #создаю списки для хранения информации о баллах учеников  

while f:
    student = list(f.readline().replace("\n",'').split(';')) 
    #записываю в этот список имя ученика и его баллы

    math += [int(student[1])]
    fis += [int(student[2])]
    rus += [int(student[3])]
    #добавляю баллы ученика в списки

    print((int(student[1]) + int(student[2]) + int(student[3]))/3)
    #вывожу оценки ученика

f.close()
#закрываю файл

for i in range(len(math)):
    res[0] += math[i]
    res[1] += fis[i]
    res[2] += rus[i]
    #подсчитываю средний результат по математике, физике и русскому(длинна у них одинаковая)

print(res[0] / len(math), res[1] / len(math), res[2] / len(math))
#вывожу результат
```

Answer (score 1):

В файле встречаются строки, в которых нет символа `;`. При этом список `student` содержит только один элемент и, когда вы пытаетесь обратиться ко второму - `student[1]`, возникает исключение.

```
for line in f:
    student = line.strip().split(';')

    if len(student) < 2:
        continue

    ...
```

Comment: Нет, везде данные разделены ' ; '. Это написано в условии.

Comment: Исключение `IndexError` может возникнуть только в случае обращения к несуществующему индексу, а `student` меньше одного элемента может содержать только в том случае, если в строке или нет символа точки с запятой или ничего нет после него. Прогоните под отладчиком и проверьте.

Comment: В каждой строке точно есть ' ; '! И даже если оставить всего строчку все равно выводит ошибку. К тому же не подсчитывает средний балл(

Comment: @ДмитрийЧеботарев, не в каждой! Последняя строка файла состоит из `'\n'`

Comment: @ДмитрийЧеботарев, кстати чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [проголосуйте за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь как минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) и/или [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)